# Deserialize Json into objects and pass them as arguments to methods

Tags: json, serialization

I am trying to make API calls to Amazon from my C# SDK. In this program, I deserialize a JSON string into C# objects and pass them as arguments into some methods to make API calls. The issue I have is the objects are not the same type with the arguments in the method signature. Below is my code. Pay attention to the "error" comments I make in the Main() method:

```
/* 
 * Selling Partner API for Listings Items
 *
 * The Selling Partner API for Listings Items (Listings Items API) provides programmatic access to selling partner listings on Amazon. Use this API in collaboration with the Selling Partner API for Product Type Definitions, which you use to retrieve the information about Amazon product types needed to use the Listings Items API.  For more information, see the [Listings Items API Use Case Guide](doc:listings-items-api-v2021-08-01-use-case-guide).
 *
 * OpenAPI spec version: 2021-08-01
 * 
 * Generated by: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen.git
 */

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using RestSharp;
using NUnit.Framework;
using SellingPartnerAPI.ListingsItemsAPI.Client;
using SellingPartnerAPI.ListingsItemsAPI.Api;
using SellingPartnerAPI.ListingsItemsAPI.Model;
using Amazon.SellingPartnerAPIAA;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using static SellingPartnerAPI.ListingsItemsAPI.Test.ListingsApiTests;

namespace SellingPartnerAPI.ListingsItemsAPI.Test
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  Class for testing ListingsApi
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This file is automatically generated by Swagger Codegen.
    /// Please update the test case below to test the API endpoint.
    /// </remarks>
    [TestFixture]
    public class ListingsApiTests
    {
        private ListingsApi instance;

        /// <summary>
        /// Setup before each unit test
        /// </summary>
        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            // TODO uncomment below to initialize instance for testing
            //instance = new ListingsApi();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up after each unit test
        /// </summary>
        [TearDown]
        public void Cleanup()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Test an instance of ListingsApi
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void InstanceTest()
        {
            // TODO uncomment below to test 'IsInstanceOfType' ListingsApi
            //Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(ListingsApi), instance, "instance is a ListingsApi");
        }

        
        /// <summary>
        /// Test DeleteListingsItem
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void DeleteListingsItemTest()
        {
            // TODO uncomment below to test the method and replace null with proper value
            //string sellerId = null;
            //string sku = null;
            //List<string> marketplaceIds = null;
            //string issueLocale = null;
            //var response = instance.DeleteListingsItem(sellerId, sku, marketplaceIds, issueLocale);
            //Assert.IsInstanceOf<ListingsItemSubmissionResponse> (response, "response is ListingsItemSubmissionResponse");
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Test GetListingsItem
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void GetListingsItemTest()
        {
            // TODO uncomment below to test the method and replace null with proper value
            //string sellerId = null;
            //string sku = null;
            //List<string> marketplaceIds = null;
            //string issueLocale = null;
            //List<string> includedData = null;
            //var response = instance.GetListingsItem(sellerId, sku, marketplaceIds, issueLocale, includedData);
            //Assert.IsInstanceOf<Item> (response, "response is Item");
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Test PatchListingsItem
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void PatchListingsItemTest()
        {
            // TODO uncomment below to test the method and replace null with proper value
            //string sellerId = null;
            //string sku = null;
            //List<string> marketplaceIds = null;
            //ListingsItemPatchRequest body = null;
            //string issueLocale = null;
            //var response = instance.PatchListingsItem(sellerId, sku, marketplaceIds, body, issueLocale);
            //Assert.IsInstanceOf<ListingsItemSubmissionResponse> (response, "response is ListingsItemSubmissionResponse");
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Test PutListingsItem
        /// </summary>
        [Test]
        public void PutListingsItemTest()
        {
            // TODO uncomment below to test the method and replace null with proper value
            //string sellerId = null;
            //string sku = null;
            //List<string> marketplaceIds = null;
            //ListingsItemPutRequest body = null;
            //string issueLocale = null;
            //var response = instance.PutListingsItem(sellerId, sku, marketplaceIds, body, issueLocale);
            //Assert.IsInstanceOf<ListingsItemSubmissionResponse> (response, "response is ListingsItemSubmissionResponse");
        }

        //**************** Classes for Listing Item Request body *****************
        public class Root
        {
            public string productType { get; set; }
            public List<Patch> patches { get; set; }
        }
        public class Patch
        {
            public string op { get; set; }
            public string operation_type { get; set; }
            public string path { get; set; }
            public List<Value> value { get; set; }
        }
        public class Value
        {
            public string fulfillment_channel_code { get; set; }
            public int quantity { get; set; }
        }

        //Reference: https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api-blog/docs/automate-your-sp-api-calls-using-the-c-sdk
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                LWAAuthorizationCredentials lwaAuthorizationCredentials = new LWAAuthorizationCredentials
                {
                    ClientId = "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    ClientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    RefreshToken = "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    Endpoint = new Uri("https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token")
                };

                ListingsApi listingsApi = new ListingsApi.Builder()
                    .SetLWAAuthorizationCredentials(lwaAuthorizationCredentials)
                    .Build();

                string sellerId = "XXXXXXXXXX";
                List<string> marketplaceIds = new List<string>();
                marketplaceIds.Add("ATVPDKIKX0DER");
                string sku = "XXX-YYY-ZZZ";
                
                //Update qty of a single product
                //Source: https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/issues/2068

                string json = @"
                    {
                        'productType': 'CELLULAR_PHONE',
                        'patches': [
                            {
                                'op': 'replace',
                                'operation_type': 'PARTIAL_UPDATE',
                                'path': '/attributes/fulfillment_availability',
                                'value': [
                                    {
                                        'fulfillment_channel_code': 'DEFAULT',
                                        'quantity': 1
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }";

                var patchListing = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

                PatchOperation.OpEnum op = PatchOperation.OpEnum.Replace;
                string path = patchListing.patches[0].path;
                List<Value> value = patchListing.patches[0].value; //this value is not accepted as an argument in PatchOperation

                List<PatchOperation> patches = new List<PatchOperation>();
                patches.Add(new PatchOperation() { Op = op, Path = path, Value = value });//Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Value>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'
                ListingsItemPatchRequest listingsItemPatchRequest = new ListingsItemPatchRequest(patchListing.productType, patches); 
                ListingsItemSubmissionResponse result = listingsApi.PatchListingsItem(sellerId, sku, marketplaceIds, listingsItemPatchRequest);
                Console.WriteLine(result.ToJson());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (LWAException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("LWA Exception when calling SellersApi#getMarketplaceParticipations");
                Console.WriteLine(e.getErrorCode());
                Console.WriteLine(e.getErrorMessage());
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            catch (ApiException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception when calling SellersApi#getMarketplaceParticipations");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here're the errors (I also commented them in my code above):

> Error CS1503 Argument 3: cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<Value> to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>

The third argument of PatchOperation accepts a List<object> type, but it does not accept List<Value>. I thought "Value" is also an object?

The classes I use in the above code can be viewed here:
ListingApi.cs: [ListingApi.cs — Codefile](https://codefile.io/f/2xeEsz3bED)
ListingsItemPatchRequest.cs: [ListingsItemPatchRequest.cs — Codefile](https://codefile.io/f/6jn64vdcS3)
PatchOperation.cs: [PatchOperation.cs — Codefile](https://codefile.io/f/07BUp2Pxdu)